# Can Anyone Identify This Icon

Tags: macos, icon

I noticed this icon next to my clock a couple days ago:

[image]

[image]

I thought it might be related to Microsoft SkyDrive, but that is a different icon.

Any ideas what program that came from? (I'm thinking it might be bloat ware)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It look like the old iSync App icon - the iSync App was AFAIK removed in OS X Lion.

Comment: That's what it looks like to me too.  You can remove it by ⌘ + dragging it from the bar.

Comment: Any idea why it may have reappeared? I'm thinking maybe when I downloaded an iOS Beta?

Comment: It has nothing to do with iOS - iOS doesn't install anything on OS X. Which version of OS X do you have ??

Comment: I just noticed it is in mine also.   It is iSync related to MobileMe  http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2074?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US